# Average of successive pairs of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

I have a table like so:

```
id | value
---+------
1  |  10
2  |  5
3  |  11
4  |  8
5  |  9
6  |  7
```

The data in this table is really pairs of values, which I need to take the average of, which should result in:

```
pair_id | pair_avg
--------+---------
1       | 7.5
2       | 9.5
3       | 8
```

I have got some other information (a pair of flags) which could also help to pair them, though they still have to be in id order. I cannot really change how the data comes to me.

As I'm more used to arrays than SQL, all I can think is that I need to loop through the table and sum the pairs. But this doesn't strike me as very SQL-ish.

#### Update

In making this minimal example, I have apparently over simplified.
As the table I am working with is the result of several selects, the IDs will not be quite so clean, apologies for not specifying this.

The table looks a lot more like:

```
id | value
----------
1  | 10
4  | 5
6  | 11
7  | 8
10 | 9
15 | 7
```

The results will be used to create a second table, I don't care about the index on this new table, it can provide its own, therefore giving the result already indicated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** your data is as clean as the question makes it seem: no NULL values, no gaps, pairs have consecutive positive numbers, starting with 1, and assuming `id` is type `integer`, it can be as simple as:

```
SELECT (id+1)/2 AS pair_id, avg(value) AS pair_avg
FROM   tbl
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

[Integer division](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE) truncates the result and thus takes care of grouping pairs automatically this way.

**If** your id numbers are not as regular but at least [strictly monotonically increasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonically_increasing_sequence#Increasing_and_decreasing) like your **update** suggests (still no NULL or missing values), you can use a surrogate ID generated with [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) instead:

```
SELECT id/2 AS pair_id, avg(value) AS pair_avg
FROM   (SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) + 1 AS id, value FROM tbl) t
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4c32de79e60f4a3fd8af3650c5163d37)*

Comment: Thankyou, unfortunately my minimal example was too minimal. I've updated the question with more information.

Comment: @RDavies: I added a 2nd solution to cover your update.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `group by` with arithmetic:

```
select row_number() over (order by min(id)), min(id), max(id), avg(id)
from t
group by floor( (id - 1) / 2 );
```

I'm not sure why you would want to renumber the ids after aggregation.  The original ids seem more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You may [use](http://rextester.com/GMB19241) `ceil` function by appliying division by 2 to `id` column as in the following select statement :

```
with t(id,value) as
(
 select 1  ,  10  union all
 select 2  ,  5   union all
 select 3  ,  11  union all
 select 4  ,  8   union all
 select 5  ,  9   union all
 select 6  ,  7    
)
select ceil(id/2::numeric) as "ID", avg(t.value) as "pair_avg"
  from t
 group by "ID"
 order by "ID";


id | pair_avg
-------------
1  | 7.5
2  | 9.5
3  | 8
```